# Python getting individual test times

Tags: python, unit-testing, timing

I have a few unit tests written using the native `unittest` module for Python 3. This is the way in which I am invoking them:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestUser)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

At the end of the test for the class it provides an overall time for how long it took to move through the whole process. I have two issues with this:

- My `setUp()` function takes a few seconds to process and I don't want to count this time
- I would prefer to get a synopsis of the time each individual test took (not all the tests in the class)

Is this possible with this module?